# Why the second regex "grep(/keyword/,@array" does not work using in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I wrote a Perl program to analyze my research data.
One function of my Perl scripts is used to count atom number in different groups (I used two arrays `@former_lists` and `@modifier_lists` to identify two groups).

If atom name is in group1 (`@former_lists`), then the variable `$cnt_former_intf++`;
if it is in group2 (`@modifier_lists`), then the variable `$cnt_modf_intf++`;
if it is oxygen atom, then `$cnt_oxyg_intf++`;
else{`$cnt_other_intf++`}.

Below is the part of my codes.

```
......
my $flg_interface;
my @former_lists;
my $cnt_former_intf=0;
my $cnt_former_exbox=0;
my $cnt_modf_intf=0;
my $cnt_modf_exbox=0;
my $cnt_oxyg_intf=0;
my $cnt_oxyg_exbox=0;
my $cnt_other_intf=0;
my $cnt_other_exbox=0;
$former_lists[0]='SI';$former_lists[1]='AL';
my @modifier_lists;
$modifier_lists[0]='CA';$modifier_lists[1]='NA';
my $hash_key;
my %hash_type_spc;
$hash_type_spc{1}='SI';
$hash_type_spc{2}='AL';
$hash_type_spc{3}='CA';
$hash_type_spc{4}='O';
$hash_type_spc{5}='H';
$hash_type_spc{6}='NA';
my @atom_type;
$atom_type[1]=1;
$atom_type[2]=2;
$atom_type[3]=3;
$atom_type[4]=4;
$atom_type[5]=5;
$atom_type[6]=6;
my $atom_id;

for($atom_id=1;$atom_id<=17587;$atom_id++)
{  $hash_key=$atom_type[$atom_id];
  $_=uc($hash_type_spc{$hash_key});chomp($_);
  if ($flg_interface ==1)   #atom is in interface box
  {
    if($_ eq 'O'){$cnt_oxyg_intf++;}
    elsif($_ eq 'H'){$cnt_hydg_intf++;}
    elsif(grep(/$_/,@former_lists)  eq 1){$cnt_former_intf++;}
    #elsif(grep(/$_/,@modifier_lists) == 1){$cnt_modf_intf++;}
    elsif(grep(/$_/,@modifier_lists) eq 1){$cnt_modf_intf++;}
    else{$cnt_other_intf++;}
  }
  else                      #atom is in extended box
  {
    if($_ eq "O"){$cnt_oxyg_exbox++;}
    elsif($_ eq "H"){$cnt_hydg_exbox++;}
    elsif(grep(/$_/,@former_lists) eq 1){$cnt_former_exbox++;}
    elsif(grep(/$_/,@modifier_lists) eq 1){$cnt_modf_exbox++;}
    else{$cnt_other_exbox++;}
  }
}#end for
print "1021 $_$atom_id \t\$flg_interface=$flg_interface \t\$cnt_former_intf=$cnt_former_intf \t\$cnt_modf_intf=$cnt_modf_intf \t\$cnt_modf_intf=$cnt_modf_intf\t\$cnt_former_exbox=$cnt_former_exbox\t\$cnt_modf_exbox=$cnt_modf_exbox\n";
$tmp=<STDIN>; 

....
```

The result shows below.

```
1021 SI6090 $flg_interface=0    $cnt_former_intf=0  $cnt_modf_intf=0    $cnt_former_exbox=0 $cnt_modf_exbox=1
1021 AL7235 $flg_interface=0    $cnt_former_intf=0  $cnt_modf_intf=0    $cnt_former_exbox=0 $cnt_modf_exbox=2
1021 CA8029 $flg_interface=0    $cnt_former_intf=0  $cnt_modf_intf=0    $cnt_former_exbox=0 $cnt_modf_exbox=3
```

where, 1021 is a label. Here,

the 1st output SI6090 should have `$cnt_former_exbox=1` instead of `0`;
the 2nd output AL7235 should have `$cnt_former_exbox=2` instead of `0`;
the 3rd output CA8029 should have `$cnt_modf_exbox=1` instead of `3`.

Any suggestion and help would be highly appreciated.
I highly appreciate it if you can share a more efficient way.

**NOTE: My data is heavy data. I have to consider running efficiency.**

Comment: I'm not sure that this ever makes sense: `grep(/$_/,@modifier_lists)` - what do you expect this to do? Can you describe the value of `$_` and the contents of `@modifier_lists` and when it makes sense to use `grep /$_/, @modifier_lists` at all? Note: `$_` will be set to each element of `@modifier_lists`, so it is not the value of `$_` further above. My suggestion is to first make the program work correctly before trying to make it work fast.

Comment: Also, please [edit] your post and add a [mcve]. Without this, we cannot really give you good advice because we cannot reproduce your situation.

Comment: Thanks Corion. I expect grep(/$_/,@modifier_lists) to search the array, if the atom name is in @modifier_lists, $cnt_modf_intf++ or $cnt_modf_exbox++. I explained it in the beginning.

Comment: And where is the atom name stored?

Comment: I update the program. Now, you may run it on your side.

Comment: No, the code you've shown is still incomplete. When running it I get `Name "main::tmp" used only once: possible typo at q:\tmp.pl line 53.
Name "main::cnt_hydg_exbox" used only once: possible typo at q:\tmp.pl line 46.
Name "main::cnt_hydg_intf" used only once: possible typo at q:\tmp.pl line 37.
Use of uninitialized value $flg_interface in numeric eq (==) at q:\tmp.pl line 34.` (and many more warnings). Also, the output I get is `1021 17588      $flg_interface=         $cnt_former_intf=0      $cnt_modf_intf=0        $cnt_modf_intf=0        $cnt_former_exbox=0     $cnt_modf_exbox=0`.

Comment: You can reduce your problem to the following code: `#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @former_lists = ('SI','AL');

$_ = 'SI';
print 'In @former_lists: ' . (grep(/$_/,@former_lists) eq 1). "\n";
print 'In @former_lists: ', join( ", ", grep(/$_/,@former_lists) ), "\n";
` . The expression `grep(/$_/,@former_lists)` will always return all elements in `@former_lists`.

Comment: The codes shown here is from my program which have almost 2000 lines. I cannot list everything here. Following your suggestion, I gave an executable codes here. I DID "use strict; use warnings;....."

Comment: Well, reducing the code is the main task you have here. And I really doubt that you did `use warnings` with the sample code you posted here. Again, the problem is in the faulty logic in `grep(/$_/,@former_lists)` (and `grep(/$_/,@any_list)`. That expression almost never makes sense. Your general program approach can be optimized but this part is simply wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everybody's time and help.

After searching online, I found the regex expression is not correct. If I want to search whether the array has the element, I need to use

```
            $tmp=uc($hash_type_spc{$hash_key});chomp($tmp);
            if($tmp eq 'O'){$cnt_oxyg_intf++;}
            elsif($tmp eq 'H'){$cnt_hydg_intf++;}
            #elsif($tmp eq "CA"){$cnt_modf_intf++;}
            elsif(grep { $tmp eq $_ } @former_lists){$cnt_former_intf++;}
            elsif(grep { $tmp eq $_ } @modifer_lists){$cnt_modf_intf++;}
            else{$cnt_other_intf++;}
```

here, I modified $_=uc($hash_type_spc{$hash_key});chomp($_) into $tmp=...

If the regex expression is changed into above, I can get the correct result. However, I do not fully understand this regex expression. Any explanation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There is no regular expression in your code. Also, it would be much faster to create a hash instead of grepping the lists. But that is a new question that you need to ask.

Comment: Thanks. I will do it later.